# Determine lbph face recognition result

Tags: opencv, design-patterns, binary, histogram, local

I am trying to recognize faces by opencv lbph algorithm.
How to get the result of match or not matched from the program.
Also what are predicted label and actual labels in lbph algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Use opencv, model = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer(),you can train a set of images by model.train() and then recognize it by using model.predict().Predict function returns a tuple, consists of label(for respective trained image) and a value(which can be used as threshold).

Answer (score 0):

using haar cascade classifire, the program recognizes faces

```
import cv2

haar_face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Face-Detection-OpenCV-master/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')

file = cv2.imread("name of your image file")

img = cv2.imread(file, 0)

faces = haar_face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5);  

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

    images.append(img[y:y+h, x:x+w])

    ids.append(namecounter)

cv2.imshow("",img)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you train a recognizer using `recognizer.train()` method you have to assign label(actual label) with each image you capture for training the recognizer. After that save that data using `recognizer.save("location")`.
Now load the saved data into recognizer and run the recognizer.predict() and it will analyze the saved data and return the possible matched label(predicted label) you have provided for the images for the current **frame/image.**

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() (for opencv 3.4 or above)
```